# Laravel 8: File Upload with Original File Name and Extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I currently have an API where it saves the uploaded image but it hashes it, turns it into strings but what I want to do now is to retain the original name of the image in the database, not the string-type.

Image Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\LessonIMG;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class LessonIMGController extends Controller
{
    public function FileUpload(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $rules = [  
            'file' => 'required',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
        
        $uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');
        
        $lesson = LessonIMG::find($id);
        $lesson->lesson_image = $request->file->hashName();

        $results = $lesson->save();
        if ($results) {
            return ["result" => "Image Added"];
        } else {
            return ["result" => "Image Not Added"];
        }

        return ["result" => $uploaded_files];
    }

    public function DeleteIMG($id)
    {
        $lesson = LessonIMG::find($id);
        if (is_null($lesson)) {
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }

        $lesson->update(['lesson_image' => null]);

        return response('Image Deleted', 200);
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for not been able to help you with your actual problem, but I can share some tips with you to have better code: 1) Don't do `Validator::make()` and then `if ($validator->fails())....`, you can just do `Validator::validate(...)` and it will automatically throw an exception going back to the `view` with the `errors` in `errors` index and it will use `422` as the error code instead of `400` (Laravel way). 2) For both methods using `$id`, you can take advantage of [`Implicit Binding`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding), so there is no need to `if (is_null(...)) return`.

Comment: FYI, the line: return ["result" => $uploaded_files]; is unreachable due to your returns in the last if statement.

Comment: Oh did not see that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get any file attribute from the request in your controller as it is documented in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#file-paths-extensions). A full reference of file methods is available in [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php)

```
$file_extension = $request->file->extension();
$file_mime_type = $request->file->getClientMimeType();
$original_file_name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

$uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');
```

Comment: I keep getting BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::getClientOriginalExtension does not exist

Comment: I now used it again and it showed no error but when I upload via postman an image named 'image.jpg' it saves as 'XsziBrSJBOLJe4j4HBxVMozweMUFHBh7Gy2bpFCn.jpg' in the folder stored.

Comment: @Lemon. `$request->file->store()` will generate a random unique string as name for you file and it will prevent name duplication. If you want to store your files with your custom name, you can use `$request->file->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');` as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

Comment: I get this now and thanks and I know that if I use that code, whenever I upload a new image, it just replaces the 'filename.jpg'. What I wanted to do is that everytime I upload a picture, it just retains the original filename

Comment: @Lemon You can achieve that using `$request->file->storeAs('images', $request->file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$request->file->extension());`

Comment: I tried this and it worked now. Thank you so much for the big help, I will study this code.  I just wonder if this code will also change the filename in the database? Because it's still hashed/string in my localhost database

Comment: @Lemon you should change this line `$lesson->lesson_image = $request->file->hashName();` to see the filename in your database. Anyway, if this answer was helpful, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original file by using `getClientOriginalName()` method:

> $filenameWithExt = $files->getClientOriginalName();

Answer (score 0):

simply do like this

```
if($file = $request->file('file')){
    $file_name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $data = $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file_name);
}
```