# Validating filename of uploaded file in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, file-upload

How can I validate the filename of uploaded image file?

**The scenario is:**

When a user upload an image the filename must its id, if not then it will throw an message that the filename must the user id.

**This is my code:**

```
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'documenttosubmit' => 'required|array',
            'datesubmitted' => 'required|array',
            'file' => 'array',
            'file.*' => 'mimetypes:' . implode(",", $allowedMimes) . '|max:' . (AppDocSubmitted::MAX_FILE_SIZE * 1024), 
        ], [
            'file.*.mimetypes' => 'File must be an image (jpg/jpeg/png) or a document (pdf).',
            'file.*.max' => 'File size must be less than the maximum size of ' . AppDocSubmitted::MAX_FILE_SIZE . 'MB',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no existing validation rule for this in Laravel.

But you can create your own validation rules, see Custom Validation Rules, in Laravel documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Also, this issue might help you: [Laravel 8: File Upload with Original File Name and Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706969/laravel-8-file-upload-with-original-file-name-and-extension)